# How to login into drupal website with their socail network accounts

Tags: drupal

I want to make a login form with Facebook and Linkedln button.
I have already installed fbconnect module.
I have gotten API key and ID.
I used facebook login block.
"Facebook Login" word appeared, but it didnt work.

Answer (score 2):

There are many modules available for this purpose:

[HybridAuth Social Login](https://drupal.org/project/hybridauth) , [OneAll Social Login](https://drupal.org/project/social-login) , [Social Login](https://drupal.org/project/sociallogin) etc..

For fbconnect module: make sure to update the Application Id & application secret @ `/admin/settings/fbconnect`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I used OneAll Social Login module. I solved problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use the "[drupal for facebook](https://drupal.org/project/fb)" module on one of my sites and it works well. I'm not sure about linkedin though.

Comment: Thank you, I solved problem using One All Social Login module.